# Como adicionar nome do autor na postagem do Wordpress?

Tags: html, html5, wordpress

Estou usando um tema no wordpress e nele não está aparecendo o nome do autor nas postagens.

Achei esse link falando sobre o código pra colocar o nome nas postagens: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author

Tentei mas mesmo assim não apareceu. Segue o código:

```html
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link       https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package    fonts
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2019, Danny Cooper
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.php GNU Public License
 */



get_header(); ?>

<div class="content-area"> 

 <?php
 
 
 if ( have_posts() ) :


  if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) :
   ?>

           <?php  the_author(); ?>

      <?php $author = get_the_author(); ?>

   <header>
    <h1 class="page-title"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>


   </header>


   <?php
  endif;

  /* Start the Loop */
  while ( have_posts() ) :

   the_post();

   /*
    * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
    * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
    * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
    */
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'archive' );




  endwhile;

 else :

  get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

 endif;
 ?>

</div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

Segue código de content-archive.php (template-parts/content-archive.php):

```html
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying page content in page.php
 *
 * @link       https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package    fonts
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2019, Danny Cooper
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.php GNU Public License
 */

?>

<article <?php post_class(); ?>>

 <?php fonts_thumbnail( 'fonts-blog' ); ?>

 <header class="entry-header">

  <div class="entry-meta">
   <?php fonts_posted_on(); ?>
  </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

  <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>

 </header><!-- .entry-header -->

 <div class="entry-content">
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  <p><a class="moretag" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Continue Reading &rarr;', 'fonts' ); ?></a></p>
 </div><!-- .entry-content -->

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Você que inseriu esses códigos: `<?php the_author(); ?>`, `<?php $author = get_the_author(); ?>`?

Comment: posta o conteúdo do arquivo 'template-parts/content', 'archive'

Comment: Isso, foi eu quem inseri esses códigos.

Comment: publiquei o código do arquivo mencionado.

Comment: Para adicionar algo a pergunta você deve editar a pergunta e adicionar o conteúdo extra.

Comment: Obrigado! Editei e adicionei.

Comment: Você quer visualizar em pagina unica a postagem ou uma lista de postagens?

Comment: em todas postagens.

Comment: Desculpa tantas perguntas, mas não estou conseguindo compreender onde esta o seu problema. Talvez para facilitar você possa indicar uma pagina especifica onde tem esse problema. Outra tentativa é de colocar no content-archive.php o comando get_the_author()

Comment: Verifica no banco de dados se esta sendo salvo a informação do autor